# SQL LEFT JOIN finding non-zero value as zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I have the following query with many LEFT JOIN clauses that has 7 result columns, the last two of which are numbers.  I'm expecting the count_non_zero column to always be equal to the count_total column (given the data I current have)

```
WITH temp_table AS ( 
SELECT 
    attr.company_name_id AS option_id, 
    attr.company_name AS option_name, 
    uj.internship_company_name_id, 
    AVG(CASE WHEN s.salary > 0 THEN s.salary END) AS average, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN s.salary > 0 THEN attr.company_name END) as count_non_zero, 
    COUNT(attr.company_name_id) as count_total 
FROM company_name attr 
    LEFT JOIN user_job_internship uj ON uj.internship_company_name_id = attr.company_name_id 
        AND attr.approved_by_administrator = 1 
    LEFT JOIN salary_internship s ON uj.user_job_internship_id = s.user_job_id 
        AND uj.job_type_id = 4 
    LEFT JOIN [user] u ON u.user_id = uj.user_id AND u.include_in_student_site_results = 1  
        AND u.site_instance_id IN (1) 
    LEFT JOIN user_education_mba_school mba ON u.user_id = mba.user_id  
        AND mba.mba_graduation_year_id NOT IN (8)  
GROUP BY attr.company_name_id, attr.company_name, uj.internship_company_name_id)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY average DESC) AS row, * 
FROM temp_table WHERE count_total >= 3) sub 
WHERE row >= 1 AND row <= 25 ORDER BY average DESC;
```

I run this query to prove that no values in the 'salary' column are returning a value of 0.

```
SELECT s.* FROM user_job_internship uj, salary_internship s 
where internship_company_name_id = 440
AND uj.user_job_internship_id = s.user_job_id
```

I'm thinking there is something that messes up the results that is causing the count_non_zero to get counts that do not exist.  Anyone have anythoughts?

Comment: I'm unclear on your question. Are you saying that count_non_zero is coming back as NULL or zero or equal to count_total or something else entirely?

Comment: I'm saying there is a scenario where for example, count_non_zero is coming back as 1 when it should be 3.  There are no values of zero, so given my current dataset, both columns should have identical values in each row.  ... But once I do start to add zero salary values, it should also work properly.

Comment: Please provide some sample data that demonstrates the problem, and indicate what results you expect. It might be helpful to reduce the number of columns and joins to the minimum required to reduce the problem. I don't think a lot of people are highly motivated to figure out what "there is a scenario" might mean simply by reverse engineering a query. Please read http://dba.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/help-us-help-you/

Comment: Ah, SQL fiddle.  Creating it now.

Comment: Just the fact that I learned about SQL fiddle from your post makes it worth a ton of upvotes to me.  I fixed it on my own. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming your count_total is greater than your count_non_zero. That is to be expected because you are using outer join to join user_job_internship and salary_internship.

Your query is including companies that do not have any internships. A company will not be included in the count_non_zero if either the salary is 0 ***or*** if there is no internship at all.

Change those two joins to inner joins and you should get your expected result.

The other option is to change your count_total to ignore companies that haven't any internship

```
count(case when s.user_job_id is not null then attr.company_name_id end) as count_total
```

You have one other slight risk. Your count_non_zero is counting company_name whereas your count_total is counting company_name_id. You could have problems if the company_name column allows NULL values.